# How to send packets over 2 networks at the same time in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, udp, amazon-vpc

If I want to send the same packets over 2 networks (but with the same destination), how can I achieve this? (e.g. through AWS and Google)

I don't mind the duplication, I can handle that at the software layer.

---

> "Same packet" as in same payload (application layer) or also same source and destination IP and port and maybe same TTL, same sequence numbers ... (network and transport layer)

I don't care about the IPs, but same port would be comfortable yes. TTL not important.
However, it would be a bonus if indeed on a network/transport layer level it would do the deduplication

> How do you currently send a single packet, what is your code?

Basically I am using UDP over zeromq in Python to send bytes.

> Do you have multiple network adapters / interfaces in place that could transport that package because otherwise what 2 networks are you possible referring to?

Yea I have multiple configurations: 1) one VPC peering connection and would like to use 2) AWS Backbone as well

Comment: "Same packet" as in same payload (application layer) or also same source and destination IP and port  and maybe same TTL, same sequence numbers ... (network and transport layer). Also, why - see [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: How do you currently send a single packet, what is your code? Do you have multiple network adapters / interfaces in place that could transport that package because otherwise what 2 networks are you possible referring to? What programming language? And why?

Comment: @luk2302 The reason "why" is that I basically hope to get speed improvements as sometimes a packet from one network will be faster than from another, and I'd act on the first time I see the data (at the software level I can add a sequence number for each data, though of course it would be even better if it is handled by some settings)

Comment: *However, it would be a bonus if indeed on a network/transport layer level it would do the deduplication"* - there is no such thing as a deduplication at the network level. Moreever these packets are not the same even if they have the same payload.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Good to know, thanks. So then I'm wondering how I can send packets over 2 different networks I guess?

Comment: @PascalVKooten: you need to have multiple interfaces (real or virtual ones like VPN) which lead to different routes and then bind the socket to the interface.